# Windows Application Driver taking long time to detect UI

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium, windows-application-driver

Windows Application driver is taking long time to detect UI even though it is present right in front of the screen. For the first few launches it works fine and then it gets rapidly slow to detect the UI. Any workaround to fix this issue even after using driver.quit?